# Load a specifc source in iframe based on URL

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am a very, very beginner at coding. And I think I am close to achieving something, but just can't get it to work just right.

Our company loads our product database into a specific program that is searchable by customers in our industry. Until I figure out how to tie into the API they provide, our website lists all of our products through iframes.

Quite often I have a client asking me to provide them a direct link to a specific product number. I'd rather not try to create a separate page with an iframe specifically linked to that one product, so I've been searching online for how to accomplish all of this.

My site is promo-central.com

I built a special search page at promo-central.com/searchby.html

I am hoping for some way to be able to give my client a link to a product (SBP26 for example) in the form of something like www.promo-central.com/searchby.html?SBP26

That will then tell the iframe on that page to load the src based on that extra info in the URL.

Here's what I currently have:

Link that i'd like to work: http://promo-central.com/searchby.html?itemnum=sbp26

The URL that should be called in this situation to correctly load the iframe would be http://www.promoplace.com/ws/ws.dll/StartSrch?DistID=36182&itemnum=sbp26

Here's the code on the page:

```
<iframe height="100%" name="WE_Frame" id="WE_Frame" src="http://www.promoplace.com/ws/ws.dll?DistID=36182"></iframe>
<script>
(function() {
var frameBaseSRC = document.getElementById("WE_Frame").src;
var frameQueryString = document.location.href.split("itemnum=")[1];
 if (frameQueryString != undefined) {
  document.getElementById("WE_Frame").src = frameBaseSRC + "&itemnum=" + frameQueryString;
 }
})();
</script>
```

To me this looks like it should work, but it doesn't work for me.

Am I way off? Or do I just have some kind of small issue?

I REALLY appreciate any help, or alternate ideas you may have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried debugging and adding a watch on the `document.getElementById("WE_Frame").src` value from your code it doesnt look as if it is doing what you are saying it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing "StartSrch" from the base iframe src that you are trying to append the query string to.  Your iframe just needs to be updated like this:

<iframe height="100%" name="WE_Frame" id="WE_Frame" src="http://www.promoplace.com/ws/ws.dll/StartSrch?DistID=36182">